# How will I tranform nested json into flatten json using underscore js

Tags: javascript, json, xml, underscore.js

```
{ "data": [ { "appointment": "string", "archived": true, "clinical-sections": [ { "clinical-template": 0,
"name": "string", "values": [ { "clinical-field": 0, "id": 0, "value": "string" } ] } ] } ] }
```

This is the json response and my goal is to transform /flatten this json into flatten json object using underscore js.

Desire output should look like this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "appointment": "string",
      "archived": true,
      "clinical_note_template": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "clinical_note_field": 0,
      "id": 0,
      "value": "string"
    
  ]
}
```

```
 var result = []; 
   _.each(response.data, function(element) { _.each(clinical_note_sections, function(aitem) { var bitem = _.extend({ appointment: element.appointment }, aitem); result.push(bitem); }); });
   return result;
```

```
The above function should return

{
  "data": [
{
"appointment": "string",
"clinical-note-template": 0
}
]
}

But It is not working and I have no idea hot to get the desire resut
```

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: What happens if the `clinical_sections` or `clinical_sections.data` arrays have more than one value?

Comment: var result = []; 
   _.each(response.data, function(element) { _.each(clinical_note_sections, function(aitem) { var bitem = _.extend({ appointment: element.appointment }, aitem); result.push(bitem); }); });
   return result;

```

```
The above function should return

{
  "data": [
{
"appointment": "string",
"clinical-note-template": 0
}
]
}

But It is not working and I have no idea hot to get the desire resut

Answer (score 1):

While you could do something with appropriate parameter destructuring like this:

```js
const convert = ({data, ...rest}) => ({
  ...rest,
  data: data.map(({
    appointment, 
    archived, 
    ['clinical-sections']: [{
      ['clinical-template']: clinical_note_template, 
      name, 
      values: [{
        ['clinical-field']: clinical_note_field, 
        id, 
        value
      }]
    }]
  }) => ({appointment, archived, clinical_note_template, name, clinical_note_field, id, value}))
})


const response = {data: [{appointment: "string", archived: true, "clinical-sections": [{"clinical-template": 0, name: "string", values: [{"clinical-field": 0, id: 0, value: "string"}]}]}]}

console .log (
  convert (response)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I suspect there is more going on than we've seen so far.

What happens if there are multiple elements in the `clinical-sections` array?  How about in the `values` array inside of that?  Which values then become your `clinical_note_template` and `clinical_note_field`?

But in any case, this might be a start.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Sauyet and yes that is a great help. I will update if there is more needed in order to your question that you had ask earlier. Thanks